# After upgrading to IE8 from 7 on Windows 2003 Intranet Home page wont Show on Startup

Tags: windows-server-2003, internet-explorer

Last week I upgraded from ie7 to 8 on our windowss 2003 terminal servers. The users home page is set to an intranet site, when you first start ie it wont show the page (404 error), but if you hit then hit refresh it comes in no problem, and has no problem once its loaded once.

Anyone any idea what might be causing it, I cant see anything obvious

Cheers
Luke

Comment: sounds like a dns problem, reboot one of the boxes and login once and before doing anything see if you can ping the host.  It might be something as simple as you need to use fqdn for your intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an add in that sophos was putting in (a website scanning thing). When I disabled the add in it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add the intranet home page url to trusted sites in Options->Security tab, might help also i'm not quite sure about that but I recently had access problems with intranet on 2003 Server R2 after upgrade to IE8 and this helped to solve my problem

Comment: I've tried that it didn't make any difference